# How to do word-break in a non-rectangle div?

Tags: html, css

### My Problem

I'm working on website which has comments that look like Facebook's comments. The text and user's name in the comments can be edited dynamically.

I can't figure out how to break a long text correctly after the user's name.

### What I've Tried

Using 'word-break: break-all' on my wrapper div.

### Examples

What i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

What i get:

[image]

### My Code (Simplified)

html:

```html
<div class="comment_wrapper">
   <div class="name"></div>
   <div class="text_wrapper">
      <div class="space_holder"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

relevant css:

```css
.text_wrapper{
    word-break: break-all;
}

.space_holder{
    width: /*Equals to name's width + 10px. Changes dynamically with
             javascript when the name is edited. */
}
```

Help much appreciated!

### EDITED: SOLUTION

This worked for me:

html:

```html
<div class="comment_wrapper">
   <div class="name"></div>
   <div class="text_wrapper">
      <div class="space_holder"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

relevant css:

```css
.text_wrapper{
    word-break: break-all;
}

.space_holder{
    width: /*Equals to name's width + 10px. Changes dynamically with
             javascript when the name is edited. */
    float: left;
}

.text{
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: https://techwelkin.com/wrap-text-around-a-div-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `float: left;` to `.space_holder` you can wrap the floated name.

```css
.text_wrapper {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.space_holder {
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_wrapper">
   <div class="name"></div>
   <div class="text_wrapper">
      <div class="space_holder">John Doe</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also had to change my "text" display to inline. I'll edit my answer with the solution.